# how to select span with jquery in a finded class?

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my HTML code:

```
<tr>                
        <th style="color: rgb(22, 149, 173);" class="index_no">1<span style="color: red;"></span></th>



                <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="squared00" name="fieldMark[correct00]" value="1">
                <label for="squared00" class="css-label_c"></label>
                </td>

                <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="squared01" name="fieldMark[correct01]" value="-1">
                <label for="squared01" class="css-label "></label>
                </td>

                <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="squared02" name="fieldMark[correct02]" value="-1">
                <label for="squared02" class="css-label "></label>
                </td>

                <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="squared03" name="fieldMark[correct03]" value="-1">
                <label for="squared03" class="css-label "></label>
                </td>

        </tr>
```

This is the jquery code I am using:

```
$("tr").each(function() {

                    var ischekZero = 0; 

        $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").each(

                function() {

                    ischekZero += parseFloat($(this).val());                                        

                });

               if (ischekZero == 0) {$(this).find("th.index_no").css( "color", "rgb(255, 0, 0)"); }
               if (ischekZero == 0) {$(this).find("th.index_no").find("span").html(*);}
});
```

The line `if (ischekZero == 0) {$(this).find("th.index_no").css( "color", "rgb(255, 0, 0)"); }`

works correctly, but the line

```
if (ischekZero == 0) {$(this).find("th.index_no").find("span").html(*);}
    });
```

shows error. How do I properly select this span? My aim is to apply a HTML asterisk between the span.

Thanks.

Comment: `.html(*)` is incorrect. `*` is not a valid variable name - it's the multiplication operator, with operands. at best it should be `.html('*')`. What are you trying to accomplish with that `*`?

Comment: What is "this" span? If you're not succeeding in finding the span, then we don't know which span you're talking about unless you explain it.

Comment: @MarcB The * can also be and all inclusive selector as well, which is what I think the OP was trying to do.  I think he was trying to get all the HTML content, but it is not clear.

Comment: @zsaat14: yes, but `.html()` either retrieves or sets the html of the match(ed) element. it's not a search function. so `.html(*)` makes literally zero sense, UNLESS you're trying to set the element's contents to a literal `*`.

Comment: @zsaat14, the OP stated, _"my aim is **apply a html asterisk** between the span"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.html(*)` is unnecessary.  The `.find()` will select the span element in the DOM.  If you want to get the HTML content of the span, then just use `.html()`.  Whatever you do, you need to get rid of the * in your `.html()`.

To add an * after the span, use this code:

```
$(this).find("th.index_no").find("span").append('*');
```

This will add an * to the end of the span.  If you want to add it at the beginning, use `.prepend`:

```
$(this).find("th.index_no").find("span").prepend('*');
```

Comment: But what if the OP _wants_ an asterisk character, `*`, inside his `span`?  Quote OP:  _"my aim is **apply a html asterisk** between the span"_

Comment: Marc B exact. the error with `.html(*)` , it should be `.html('*')`.